# Unable to properly convert array of complex objects to CSV

Tags: javascript, typescript, csv

I have an array of complex objects, which may contain arrays of more objects. I want to convert these to a CSV file. Whenever there's a list of objects, the data is parsed as `[object Object]`. If a person has two emails, for example, I want to print these emails in two lines, and so on for each object. Addresses may be concatenated to one string, for example "France, Paris, someStreet 15".

The code is in this [pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ewajNy).

Here's the data:

```
var names = [
        {
          Name: [{First: "Peter", Last:"john"}],
          WorkPlace: [{Company: "Intel", emails: ["jack@intell.com","admin@intell.com"]}],
          Age: 33.45,
          Adress: [{Country:"UK", city: "London", street:"Oak", strtNumber:16},
                  {Country:"Italy", city: "MIlan", street:"Zabin", strtNumber:2}]
        },
        {
            Name: [{First: "jack", Last:"Smith"}],
          WorkPlace: [{Company: "Intel", emails: ["jack@intell.com","admin@intell.com"]}],
            Age: 30,
          Adress: [{Country:"Portugal", city: "Lisbon", street:"crap", strtNumber:144},
                  {Country:"Greece", city: "Athenes", street:"Hercules", strtNumber:55}]
        },
        {
            Name: [{First: "jon", Last:"snow"}],
          WorkPlace: [{Company: "Intel", emails: ["jack@intell.com","admin@intell.com"]}],
            Age: 50,
          Adress: [{Country:"Middle earth", city: "Winterfell", street:"raven", strtNumber:4345},
                  {Country:"Narnia", city: "Jacksonvile", street:"Great crap", strNumber:34}]
        },
    ];
```

Right now this is the output:

[image]

Comment: Tried Json.stringify()..??

Comment: I dont need a json, I need a well formatted file, with titles.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/json2csv try this one

Comment: Thanks but it does not work.. prints just a long json and does not format it like a table..

Answer (score 0):

The mistake is inside your converArrayOfObjectsToCSV-method, as the result of 'item[key]' is an array (in case of 'Name') and you need to specify further how to handle this array, as it otherwise will only be written out to [object Object]. 
You will have to access the element with i.e. item[key][index] and the iterate over its properties and print them as you need them.

Answer (score 0):

The **[object Object]** indicates the data needs further conversion to get the desired output.

Here is an updated [CodePen](https://codepen.io/chrisweb/pen/vqwzqd) with an example conversion.

The conversion routine provided uses **Object.values()** to convert all data:

```
function parseArrayOfObjects(arrayOfObj){
  return arrayOfObj.map(item => 
    Object.values(item).join(" ")) // convert each array item to it's values
    .join(" ") // convert final array to string
    .replace(",", " "); // remove any commas to preserve csv format
}
```

Of course, your needs may dictate other conversions, so adjust as needed.